# Is it possible to set background image in Symfony 1.4 action file?

Tags: symfony-1.4

I would like to customize background image for logged user. Is is possible to change bg image in action file?

```
$bg_image = $this->getUser()->getBgImage();
/* and here function to change body background image */
???
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your layout file (/apps/frontend/templates/layout.php), you can change the background-image css attribute, for example :

```
<body style="background-image:url ('<?php echo $sf_user->getBgImage(); ?>');">
```